# Premade wizard: Attack bonus on Quarterstaff unclear

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation

Here is a screenshot of the premade Ezren the wizard class. ([Public source](http://paizo.com/download/pathfinder/PZO1119-Pregens.zip))

[image: Ezren]

It has two weapons, the quarterstaff and a light crossbow. Now I fail to understand how the Attack Bonus on the Weapons are calculated. The class AB is +0, which is correctly noted under "F" but it has a +1 for the Quarterstaff.

I try not to confuse damage with attack bonus. I understand that a standard quarterstaff has a **damage** of 1d6 and Ezren's calculated damage is 1d6 + STR mod (+1), fine.

But what's with the attack bonus? Nowhere it is noted that it is magic one, which would explain a +1 AB but then would also have another +1 damage
I cannot find any indicators of in my beginners rulebook or [online](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Attack-Bonus) where this (I assume?) Base Attack Bonus of +1 stems from.

Hints are appreciated.

---

With @kviiris help I realized some maybe important details: In the beginner char sheet the term attack bonus is used for several things. The classes and levelling AB (under F) is called the Base Attack Bonus BAB in the char sheets in the full game and everywhere in the web. Furthermore I find it very irritating that under G there is another Attack Bonus for a weapon which is misleading IMHO. Example: Melee Attack should already sum up your full AB without the weapon, which is BAB (or AB from *Class Features F*) + STR Mod (or DEX in some special abilities). This actually is the hero's AB regardless of weapon. Now the weapon has also an AB noted, which I assume is currently the same field calculated in the Melee Attack row.

This is confusing at best, because I would use the weapon's AB to note the weapon's AB values (and not the current Melee Attack row value), a magical staff would, for example, add +1 AB to your Melee Attack row value. So while your Melee Attack would be still +1, you would also add the +1 from the weapon to a total of +2. (Note: At the same time I would change the damage, which is *1d6 + STR Mod (+1)* to *1d6 + Magical (+1) + STR Mod (+1)* )

These things might be obvious in the full rules but are very confusing (at least for me) in the beginners box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the character's strength modifier, +1.

See the [reference document](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/combat.html):

> Your attack bonus with a melee weapon is the following:
>
> Base attack bonus + Strength modifier + size modifier

The character has 0 base attack bonus, +1 strength modifier and the weapon is appropriately sized, totaling to +1 bonus.

Comment: I just saw it too :), unfortunately the beginner box has a somewhat bad description of it: Melee: 1d20 + attack bonus + STR mod + other modifiers. Which should be 1d20 + base attack bonus + STR mod + other modifiers as stated in your and also mine reference link. The non-beginner character sheets also differentiate between BAB and weapon AB with different naming, which the beginner sheets don't.